# Server doesn't recognize file with GET

Tags: php, http, query-string

I have a problem with server and too upset and don't know what to do, never met such problem.
The `index2.php` file is ok and working, but when I add `$_GET` it doesn't find the file.
For example `index2.php` works, but `index2.php&p=1` doesn't work or `index2.php&t=2` or any `&`, doesn't work.

It says:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index2.php&p=2 was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Any rewriting rules or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try index2.php?p=1 i.e whenever you are using query string to pass parameters use ? mark and if you are passing more than one parameter then use & operator to pass multiple parameters.

Comment: lool... I'm lost, long ago I didn't code... Thanks...
Never thought I can do such mistake... thanks Jayant Jadhav ;)